# Windows - How to Ignore External Monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I currently have a three monitor setup - two external displays and one laptop screen.

At times, I have something else connected to one of the monitors (a different computer), so I can't see the content that the windows is projecting onto the external monitors. Often times information gets blocked or windows will open up an application in a window that is being hidden.

Is there an easy way to stop displaying on a currently connected external monitor? Looking at display settings, I can't seem to find anything.

I can't constantly be removing Display cords since they are hooked up to a dock that lives behind my desk.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI way to disconnect the display is to:

1. Open **Settings** -> **System** -> **Display**.
2. Select the monitor that you want to stop displaying to.
3. Under **Multiple Displays** dropdown select **Disconnect this display**.
4. Select **Keep changes** when prompted.

To reconnect:

1. Open **Settings** -> **System** -> **Display**.
2. Select the monitor that you want to reconnect.
3. Under **Multiple Displays** dropdown select **Extend desktop to this display**.
4. Select **Keep changes** when prompted.

Comment: Wow. That is not as intuitive as it could be. That totally works. Was worried that it wouldn't keep the display positions, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Great solution... now only if there is a way to automate this